# PHP regex - Ignore Parenthesis and double i

Tags: php, regex

I have three separate strings as follows:

```
California (Socal)
New Jersey
Ohio II
```

I want to extract the following string from each respectively:

```
California
New Jersey
Ohio
```

So basically I want to drop anything that begins with a parenthesis or a double I. Here is what I have tried but I'm not sure how to proceed:

```
([a-z]+.[a-z]+)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `preg_replace` will be easy for this:

```
$arr = array(
  "California (Socal)",
  "New Jersey",
  "Ohio II"
);

foreach($arr as $a){
    $a = preg_replace("/(II|\().*/", "", $a);
}
```

Here its replacing anything after the `II` or `(` with empty.